# How to change SeparatorColor of Selected Item in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

I've got the following UITableView

```
_navigationList = new UITableView
    {
        Source = UINavigationTableViewSource,
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(43, 43, 43), // #2b2b2b - same as Android
        SeparatorColor = UIColor.FromRGB(27,27,27), // #1b1b1b - same as Android
        SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero,
        ScrollEnabled = true
    };
```

The `UINavigationTableViewSource` is using a custom `UITableViewCell`

```
public sealed class UINavigationTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public new readonly UILabel TextLabel;

    public UINavigationTableViewCell(string cellId)
        : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
    {
        TextLabel = new UILabel(new RectangleF(10, 0, Bounds.Width, 40)) {TextColor = UIColor.White}; // properly position the label.

        SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero; // make the boarder go all the way across the list item

        ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(43, 43, 43); // #2b2b2b - same as Android

        var activeOrb = new UIImageView(new RectangleF(0,0,10,Bounds.Height))
            {
                Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Images/active_orb.png"), 
                ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            };
        SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(43, 43, 43) };
        SelectedBackgroundView.Add(activeOrb);

        ContentView.Add(TextLabel);
    }
}
```

Everything is looking the way we want except for the ugly white line on a selected row.

**How do I change the SeparatorColor when a row is selected?**

[image]

Comment: There are some iOS 7 bugs connected with the separator and selection. You'll find a lot of suggested workarounds if you search stack overflow. In my opinion, the best approach is to set the separator style to None and draw the separator yourself as oart of each cell's background.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. Works ok I suppose, but man... Bugs in my own code are hard enough to deal with without having to deal with bugs in the platform :/

Comment: Welcome to the real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had never programmed in xamarin, but i worked on ios(5-7) sdk.
I would suggest you to dont use any seperators.Instead add the seperator line as `view`(**height-1pixel**;width-cellWidth) to your cell.

---

*edit by ChaseFlorell - working example*

```
_navigationList = new UITableView
    {
        Source = UINavigationTableViewSource,
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(43, 43, 43), // #2b2b2b - same as Android
        SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None,
        ScrollEnabled = true
    };
Add(_navigationList);
```

```
public sealed class UINavigationTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public new readonly UILabel TextLabel;

    public UINavigationTableViewCell(string cellId) : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
    {
        // The default state
        TextLabel = new UILabel(new RectangleF(10, 0, Bounds.Width, 40)) { TextColor = UIColor.White }; // properly position the label.

        ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(43, 43, 43); // #2b2b2b - same as Android
        ContentView.Add(Separator(Bounds));
        ContentView.Add(TextLabel);

        // todo: move colors to a config file.

        // The selected state
        var activeOrb = new UIImageView(new RectangleF(0, 0, 10, Bounds.Height))
            {
                Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Images/active_orb.png"),
                ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            };
        SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(43, 43, 43) };
        SelectedBackgroundView.Add(Separator(Bounds));
        SelectedBackgroundView.Add(activeOrb);
    }

    private static UIView Separator(RectangleF bounds)
    {
        return new UIView(new RectangleF(0, 0, bounds.Width, 1))
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(27, 27, 27)
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a quick edit to your answer to show a working example. Thanks for the tip!